# How to change javascript variable at appropriate scope based on success/failure of ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, scope

I want to edit a javascript variable based on whether or not a file exists. Can I achieve something like this?

```
     var url="Content/Features/column1.html";
     var url2="";
     $.ajax({
            url: url,
            error: function()
            {   
               url2 = "something";
            },
            success: function()
            {
                url2 = "something else";
            }
        });
```

My understanding is that the typical issue here is the async in ajax. Should I be using a callback method or a promise in some fashion?

Maybe something like:

```
var url="Content/Features/column1.html";
     var url2="";
var result = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        error: function()
        {   
           url2 = "something";
           handleData(url2);
        },
        success: function()
        {
            url2 = "something else";
            handleData(url2);
        }
    }); 

response = function handleData( responseData ) {
    return responseData;
}
```

Or even:

```
var url="Content/Features/column1.html";
var url2="";
function test(url) {
    return $.ajax(
    {
        url: url
    }
    );
}

test().done(function(url2) {
    url2= "something"

}).fail(function() {
    url2= "something else"
});
```

How can I change url2 at the same scope in which it was declared? Or is there a way to return a value from a callback function and change url2 based on that?

Alternatively, is there a better way to check if this file exists? (And before you tell me that browsers don't allow ajax requests to local files, please know that I am using node-webkit, not a browser)

None of these attempts worked quite right, but please let me know if I'm close. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since AJAX is async in nature you cannot return a value from your function and instead need to implement a callback. You could do something like this:

```
function getURL2(callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};

    var url="Content/Features/column1.html";
    var url2="";
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            error: function()
            {   
               callback("something");
            },
            success: function()
            {
                callback("something else");
            }
        }); 


}



getURL2(function(url2) {
   // the call is complete and url2 is set correctly!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer! Do you have time to explain what's going on here? How can I access url2 outside of this function?
When debugging, I see url2= "something" at the end of the getURL2 call. Is that just within the scope of the of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var url1 = "Content/Features/column1.html"
, res = {"url2": void 0} // `this` `context` within `$.ajax` call at `request`
, request = function request(url1, res) {
  return $.ajax({
             context: res // set `this` to `res` object
             , url: url1
             , method: "GET"
             , success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                 this.url2 = "something"; // `success` 
                 return this // return `this` : `res`
               }
             , error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 this.url2 = jqxhr.status === 404 // `404` , `Not Found`
                             ? "somethingElse" // `error`
                               // if `error` other than `404`, 
                               // return `jqxhr.status`
                             : jqxhr.status; 
                 return this // return `this` : `res`

               }
          });
};
request(url1, res).always(function(response) {
   // `this` : `res` 
   console.log(response.status
               , response.statusText
               , response.state()
               , this.url2); // if `error` , `somethingElse` , else `something` 
});
```

See [jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) at `context` , [deferred.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

```js
var url1 = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a6997f09de9b68c59b2/"
           + "raw/f7d7b756005ad6d2b88cf0211f78a2990d7d2dc7" + "123" // `404` `error`
, res = {"url2":void 0}
, request = function request(url1, res) {
  return $.ajax({
             context: res
             , url: url1
             , method: "GET"
             , success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                 this.url2 = "something";
                 return this
               }
             , error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 this.url2 = jqxhr.status === 404 
                             ? "somethingElse" 
                             : jqxhr.status;
                 return this
                             
               }
          });
};
request(url1, res).always(function(response) {
   console.log(response.status
               , response.statusText
               , response.state()
               , this.url2);
   document.write(JSON.stringify(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```